# Как скопировать свойства одного объекта в другой?

Tags: объекты, javascript

Нужно скопировать свойство одного объекта в другой.

Comment: @Yres, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Yres, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Когда же люди научатся гуглить 
http://bit.ly/1vEM0O0
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620296/copying-javascript-object-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция принимает объект obj1 и obj2, возвращает obj1, со свойствами из obj2, если свойства совпадает то перезаписывает их.  Здесь приведен код для копирования объекта со всеми свойствами. Внимание: если в свойстве будет объект, то его свойства не будут скопированы, для "глубокого" копирования нужно применять рекурсию:

```
function extend(obj1, obj2){
    for (key in obj2){
      obj1[key]=obj2[key];
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает, вставил в свой код, но не совсем так, пишет замечание.  
Не срабатывает, как ожидалось, для случая `extend({foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 1})`. Ожидалось, что функция вернет `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`.

Comment: Какое замечание? У меня она выводит  Object {foo: 1, bar: 2}
http://plnkr.co/edit/0F12dqCp9TJS3qXdmxTa?p=preview